# Finding total number of unique factorization

Tags: c++

I want to find total factors of any number.
In number theory, factorization is the breaking down of a composite number into smaller non-trivial divisors, which when multiplied together equal the original integer. Your job is to calculate number of unique factorization(containing at least two positive integers greater than one) of a number.

> For example: 12 has 3 unique factorizations: 2*2*3, 2*6, 3*4 . Note:
>   3*4 and 4*3 are not considered different.

I have attempted to find that but not getting exact for all.
Here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int count=0;
void factor(int n,int c,int n1)
{
    for(int i=n1; i<n ; i++)
    {
        if(c*i==n)
            {count++;
            return;}
        else
        if(c*i>n)
            return;
        else
        factor(n,c*i,i+1);
    }
    return;
}
int main()
{
    int num,n;
    cin>>num;
    for(int i=0 ; i<num ; i++)
    {
        cin>>n;
        count=0;
        factor(n,1,1);
        cout<<count<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input is number of test cases followed by test-cases(Numbers).

> Example : Input: 3 12 36 3150
>
> Output: 3 8 91

Comment: Your question title is wrong, you are looking for number of unique factorization, not number of factors, for 12 number of factors is 6: 1 2 3 4 6 12

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for number of factorizations of a number which are unique.
For this I think you need to find the count of number of prime factor of that number. Say for

```
12 = 2, 2, 3
```

Total count = 3;
For 2, 2, 3 we need

```
(2*2)*3  ~ 4*3
2*(2*3)  ~ 2*6
2*2*3    ~ 2*2*3
```

To solve this we have idea found in Grimaldi, discrete and combinatorial mathematics.
To find number of ways of adding to a number(n) is 2^(n-1) -1. For 3 we have...

```
3 =
1+1+1
2+1
1+2
```

Total count =  2^(3-1) -1 = 4-1 = 3

We can use analogy to see that

```
1+1+1 is equivalent to 2*2*3
1+2 is equivalent to 2*(2*3)
2+1 is equivalent to (2*2)*3

Say number of prime factors = n
So we have number of factorizations = 2^(n-1)-1
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int power(int x, int y)
{
    int prod =1, i ;
    for(i=1; i<=y;i++) prod *= x;
    return prod;
}

int main()
{
    int number,div;    
    int count  = 0, ti, t;
    printf("Input: ");    
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(ti=1; ti<=t;ti++)
    { 
        scanf("%d", &number);
        div = 2;count = 0;
        while(number != 0)
        {
            if(number%div!=0) div = div + 1;            
            else 
            {
                number = number / div;
                //printf("%d ",div);
                count++;
                if(number==1) break;
            }
        }
        printf("%d ", power(2,count-1)-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yea, thee is something wrong in the idea. The problem is it doesn't take care all partitions. I believe the answer lies in number of non overlapping partitions of set of prime factors. Please look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430599/number-of-all-possible-groupings-of-a-set-of-values (catalan numbers). The problem here is some partittions are similar

Answer (score 1):

Using `mod` is really useful in attempting to factor:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= fnum; ++i){ //where fnum is the number you wish to factor
    if(!(fnum % i)) ++count;
}
return count;
```

Of cross this is the number of factors, not unique factors, if you want the number of unique factors, you have to do some additional work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to realize that of all permutations, precisely one is sorted. `2 * 4 * 7 * 3` gives the same result as `2 * 3 * 4 * 7`. That means that when you've found one factor, you should not check the remainder for *lower* factors. However, you should check if the same factor appears again: `12 = 2 * 2 * 3`. The sequence `2 2 3` is also sorted.

BTW, you should give your variables clearer names, or at least add some comments describing them.